# Is there a different way to copy the .dll file from one project to beside my executable file in my startup project?

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2019, premake

I'm using premake5 to build a c++ visual studio 2019 application engine. I need to figure out why it's not working after I used premake5 to build my projects.

I have tried to change the architecture to only x64 but it insists the cfg.system is x86_64.

```
workspace "Engine_Autry"
    architecture "x64"


    configurations
    {
        "Debug",
        "Release",
        "Dist"
    }

outputdir = "%{cfg.buildcfg}-%{cfg.system}-%{cfg.architecture}"

project "Engine"
    location "Engine"
    kind "SharedLib"
    language "C++"

    targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.nam}")
    objdir ("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.nam}")

    files
    {
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.h",
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.cpp"
    }

    includedirs
    {
        "%{prj.name}/vendor/spdlog/include"
    } 

    filter "system:windows"
        cppdialect "C++17"
        staticruntime "On"
        systemversion "latest"

        defines
        {
            "APP_PLATFORM_WINDOWS",
            "APP_BUILD_DLL"
        }

        postbuildcommands
        {
            {"{COPY} %{cfg.buildtarget.relpath} ../bin/" .. outputdir .. "/Sandbox"}
        }


    filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines "APP_DEBUG"
        symbols "On"

    filter "configurations:Release"
        defines "APP_RELEASE"
        optimize "On"

    filter "configurations:Dist"
        defines "APP_DIST"
        optimize "On"


project "Sandbox"
    location "Sandbox"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    language "C++"

    targetdir ("bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.nam}")
    objdir ("bin-int/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.nam}")

    files
    {
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.h",
        "%{prj.name}/src/**.cpp"
    }

    includedirs
    {
        "Engine/vendor/spdlog/include",
        "Engine/src"
    } 

    links
    {
        "Engine"
    }

    filter "system:windows"
        cppdialect "C++17"
        staticruntime "On"
        systemversion "latest"

        defines
        {
            "APP_PLATFORM_WINDOWS"
        }


    filter "configurations:Debug"
        defines "APP_DEBUG"
        symbols "On"

    filter "configurations:Release"
        defines "APP_RELEASE"
        optimize "On"

    filter "configurations:Dist"
        defines "APP_DIST"
        optimize "On"
```

It was working before I used premake5 to build my engine.

```
Error   MSB3073 The command "IF EXIST ..\bin\Debug-windows-x86_64\Engine.dll\ (xcopy /Q /E /Y /I ..\bin\Debug-windows-x86_64\Engine.dll ..\bin\Debug-windows-x86_64\Sandbox > nul) ELSE (xcopy /Q /Y /I ..\bin\Debug-windows-x86_64\Engine.dll ..\bin\Debug-windows-x86_64\Sandbox > nul)
:VCEnd" exited with code 2. Engine  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 138
```

Comment: `IF EXIST` will never work with `Engine.dll\` because filenames can't end in a backslash. Code 2 is typically *file not found*, which means something isn't located where your batch code thinks it should be.

Comment: What you need to do is to convert the logic you have in your program in to some decision matrix. If you are happy with the result, chances are good that you'll find it easy to follow afterwards too. You are "logging", right?

Comment: I am logging but it guess i need to work on my logging situation :\ I am making quite a jump in proficiency with this project. I'm pretty sure i understand most of what im doing but logging and exceptions still are sort of confusing. Im guessing its similar to how i would go about 'testing'?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while following thecherno's tutorials.

There were two issues that caused this problem:

1. In my post build command, the directory was not correct. In your case, the directory is correct.
2. Set Sandbox as Startup project. I think you forgot to do this after you rebuild and reloaded Visual Studio.

Try that and let me know.